# dex express controls how to get ID value from ComboBox

Tags: asp.net, combobox, devexpress

I have ID Number and name. I am using a datacontrol and this "Select **Number**, Name from My Table"
I can see both in the combobox, but if I pick one I can't get any data from it. what do I do?
I have used native .NET and get the ID value using this>
    Protected Sub lstWorkList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstWorkList.SelectedIndexChanged

```
    Try

        Session("gblWorkerNumber") = Me.lstWorkList.SelectedValue.ToString
```

but in dev express there is no "post back" and I can't get their example to work either.
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Not IsCallback) Then
            CmbCountry.Value = "Mexico" ' I want to get my **Number** into a session var
            FillCityCombo("Mexico")
        End If
    End Sub

seems to me like their example just hardcodes "Mexico" in ??? how does that work anyway?

Their Example is on this page: 
http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxComboBox/ClientAPI.aspx

Comment: The example provided works fine for me. Have you tried it in different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was after,  the **.Value**

```
   Protected Sub cbxWorkerName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxWorkerName.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("WorkerNumber") = Me.cbxWorkerName.Value
    ' in native .NET it is either .selectedindex or .selectedValue one gives the name and the other gives the Number
End Sub
```